# Jhipster app memory consumption on Amazon ec2

Tags: java, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jhipster

My application is just a bigger version of the default Jhipster app.. I even have no Cache.

I deployed it successfully on an Amazon free tier t1.micro instance.

I experienced some random 503 errors. I checked the health of the instance and it sometimes said "no data sent" some other times "93% of memory is in use". Now it's down (red).

I cloned the environment, then terminated the original one. I get those various errors.

I deployed the war with `Dev` spring profile but I believe it's not what is causing this much horror.

Do I need to configure the java memory usage ? Why could the app be this memory hungry?

I posted the question on StackOverflow as I am caring more about performance tuning of the deployed Jhipster war but if you think it's more a problem with Amazon please let me know why you think that.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deploy the application on a instance with much more memory ie an t2.large (8GB)
The size on an existing instance can be altered by using the console "stop", find the console "instance settings" "instance type" change and start again

Ensure that your application has a method for attaching jconsole to it available (apparently the development version does, with jmx).  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html for more information on jconsole

Run the application and monitor the nice graphs in jconsole

See what the peak is over a few days of normal use.  Also log on to the server with ssh and use `free -m` to see the system memory use ( see http://www.linuxatemyram.com/ for a guide to interpreting the data )

Once you know the actual amount of RAM it uses choose an appropriate instance size, see http://www.ec2instances.info/

You might need to adjust the -Xmx setting, I don't know the specifics with jhipster but this is a common requirement for java applications

Comment: I upgraded to the t2.micro instance as it's the best option for the free tier. Thank you for the info though !! very useful.